# Why do I need to make 'head' equal to 'prev' to finish reversing a Linked List?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

sorry for the awkward question title. I don't really know how to explain without a code example. I have implemented a Linked List using generics, and I am trying to reverse it.

```
public Node<T> reverse() {
Node<T> prev = null;

while (head != null) {
  Node<T> next = head.next;
  head.next = prev;
  prev = head;
  head = next;
  System.out.println("head: " + head.next + "\nprev: " + prev.next);
}
head = prev;
return prev;
}

head = prev;
```

My question is, why is this required?

My LinkedList outputs:
[output]

But without the `head = prev;` line it simply outputs blank []. Is this something to do with generics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, It has nothing to do with `generics`, Looking at your reverse method, initially, there are three nodes `prev` pointing to null, `head` pointing to start of the linked list, and `next` pointing to `head`'s next node. At each step you are moving each node in forward direction until it is reversed, so after completion, your `prev` node will point to the tail of the linked list which is in fact the start of the reversed linked list, and both `head` and `next` pointing to null. So `head = prev` is needed to make the `head` point to the starting node of the reversed linked list.

Comment: Hi. thanks for taking the time to reply. My Main issue is that I seem to not have this issue if I don't inlclude it on this version:

https://leetcode.com/submissions/detail/597095512/

Why does the version above work, while mine does not? Keep in mind I am referring specifically to the omission of thre 'head = prev' part. From my view, they are exactly the same; if I don't include the line before return that is.

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: Whoops! Try this: https://pastebin.com/HxPJ4KgR

Comment: In this version, the returned value is a correct node which is `prev`, In your version also the returned node is `prev` which is correct but the `head` node is global. So it is needed for you to either assign `head = prev` or `head = reverse()`

Comment: Ah, so its essentially a scoping issue? I.e., if I were to create 'Node head' within the parameter paretheses it would fix it?

It would make sense, as I actually removed that on purpose as I simply wanted to call it as 'list.reverse()'.

Comment: @Jonny Yes if you intend to use some node as head, you need to assign it to `prev` before using.

Answer (score 0):

*TLDR; Because at end of while loop, 'head' points to null, not the reversed list.

--

Let’s understand your code by an example:
List:   3 -> 6 -> 9 -> null
head points to 3.
// 1

```
Node<T> prev = null;
while(head != null) // true
Node<T> next = head.next; // next -> 6, as head.next points to Node with element 6
head.next = prev; // head->next = null, earlier it pointed to Node with element 6, prev is null
prev = head; 
head = next;
```

Current state:

```
null <- 3 6 -> 9 -> null
Now, prev points to 3, head points to 6.
// 2
while(head != null) // true
Node<T> next = head.next; // next -> 9, as head.next points to Node with element 9
head.next = prev; // head->next =3, earlier it pointed to Node with element 9, prev is 3
prev = head; 
head = next;
```

Current state:

```
null <- 3 <- 6 9 -> null
Now, prev points to 6, head points to 9.    

// 3
while(head != null) // true
    Node<T> next = head.next; // next -> null, as head.next points to null
    head.next = prev; // head->next =6, earlier it pointed to null, prev is 6
    prev = head; 
    head = next;
```

Current state:

```
null <- 3 <- 6 <- 9
Now, prev points to 9, head points to null.

// 4
while(head != null) // false

Now, head points to null and you need to return reversed linked list.
head = prev; // prev points to the node with element 9.
// null <- 3 <- 6 <- 9 <- prev (or head) as head and prev are equal.
return prev; // will return the reversed linked list.
return head; // will return the reversed linked list as both prev and head are equal.
```